# Get ID of php populated select option

Tags: php, mysql

I populate an HTML Select drop down using data from a MySQL table. What I need to do is fetch the ID of that option and submit it to a different table, but have no clue how to do it. Here's how it's populated:

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT RaceName FROM Race ORDER BY RaceName"); 
                ?>
<select class="pure-input-2" required="required" name="raceName">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected>Select a race</option>
        <?php while($option = $query->fetch_object()){ ?>
            <option><?php echo $option->RaceName; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
```

How can I then retrieve the ID of the selected option to submit to a different table?

I guess in the SELECT query I could also select the RaceID, but how can I then pass this through the submit button?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT RaceID, RaceName FROM Race ORDER BY RaceName"); 
                ?>
<select class="pure-input-2" required="required" name="raceId">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected>Select a race</option>
        <?php while($option = $query->fetch_object()){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $option->RaceID; ?>"><?php echo $option->RaceName; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
</select>
```

So the value of `$_POST['raceId']` will be the option value ie.RaceId.

Comment: I need to be able to submit the RaceID AND the RaceName. How would I do this in this format?

Comment: Ya user will only see race name. If you both want to submit RaceID and RaceName you can seperate them with delimeter and then retrive by splitting it in the server. Eg-: `value="<?php echo $option->RaceID; ?>,<?php echo $option->RaceName; ?>"`

Comment: Thanks very much, original solution was all I needed in the end!